# Mix histogram and density plot in ggplot2 different datasets

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I want to have a plot where I display the histogram of one dataset and the density plot of another dataset.

I can make both histograms and density plots, but I cannot get the undesired histogram/density plots to go away.

For example:

```
    library(ggplot2)
      set.seed(1234); dat <- data.frame(cond = factor(rep(c("A","B"), each=200)), 
              rating = c(rnorm(200),rnorm(200, mean=.8)))

    # Overlaid histograms
    ggplot(dat, aes(x=rating, fill=cond)) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),binwidth=.5, alpha=.5, position="identity") + geom_density(alpha=.3)
```

gives me the a plot that looks like this:
[image]

I want to get rid of (for example) the red histogram and the blue density plot, leaving me with a blue histogram and a red density plot.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I would do it, by separating the calls in ggplot layers by separate datasets, so that each layer is only dealing with what you want it to. I have made the data sets different to make it more apparent.:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1234); 
dat <- data.frame(cond = factor(rep(c("A"), each=200)), 
                              rating = c(rnorm(200),rnorm(200, mean=.8)))
dat2 <- data.frame(cond = factor(rep(c("B"), each=200)), 
               rating = c(rnorm(200),rnorm(200, mean=.6)))

# Overlaid histograms
ggplot() +
    geom_histogram(data = dat, aes(x=rating, fill=cond, y=..density..),binwidth=.5, alpha=.5, position="identity") +
    geom_density(data = dat2, aes(x=rating, fill=cond), alpha=.3)
```

[image: Overlaid plots with two different datasets]

Comment: I like this one better, cleaner.

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't preserve the colors, but in general what you want to do is have a different data= argument for the overall plot and one of the geom's:

```
ggplot(dat[dat$cond=="A",], aes(x=rating)) + 
geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),binwidth=.5, alpha=.5, position="identity") + 
geom_density(alpha=.3,data=dat[dat$cond=="B",])
```

[image]

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you this was exactly what I needed!